# Jquery-mobile repeatedly printing javascript when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a javascript function which reads from a json file and prints the contents onto a menu grid which is created by running through the array and printing them one by one. 
I originally had the problem that the JS would not display at all but I was told that my code needed to go into the content div in order to get printed. Now that the JS is in the content div it will print but every time I re-load the page it prints again leaving two menus, and if re-loaded again 3 menus etc. I tried putting simple a boolean variable and if loop to print the loop and then turn false but as the variable is being re-initialised every time the page is loaded I am at a loss. Here is the html & JS code and if anyone had any idea what I can do I would appreciate it:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>




</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="Page1">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
      <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="flip" data-icon="back"> Back </a>
      <a href="info.html" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-transition="flip" data-icon="info"> Info </a>
      <h2>Main Menu</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c" id="Page1_Content">

      <div class="ui-grid-b">

      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var json = {
       "tcontent": [{
        "Chapter": "1",
        "Name": "General Principles of Antibiotic Perscribing",
        "url":"<a href='general_principles.html'>",
        "Background":"yellow"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "2",
        "Name": "Note on meticillin resistant SA",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "3",
        "Name": "Empirical Therapy Guidelines:",
        "url": "<a href='empirical.html'>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "4",
        "Name": "Treatment of Malaria",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "5",
        "Name": "Antibiotic Prophylaxis:",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "6",
        "Name": "Aminoglycoside and Glycopeptide dosing and monitoring:",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "7",
        "Name": "Splenectomy: vaccination and antibiotic prophylaxis",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "8",
        "Name": "Restricted Antimicrobials",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "9",
        "Name": "Topical Antibiotics",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "10",
        "Name": "Antimicrobials and Renal Failure",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "11",
        "Name": "Antimicrobials and Hepatic Disease",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "12",
        "Name": "Administration of IV Antimicrobials",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }, {
        "Chapter": "13",
        "Name": "Penicillin allergy & other beta-lactam containing antibiotics",
        "url":"<a>",
        "Background":"background-color:red"
      }]
    };

    var grid= new Array();
    grid[0]= "<div class='ui-block-a'>";
    grid[1]= "<div class='ui-block-b'>";
    grid[2]= "<div class='ui-block-c'>";
    grid[3]= "<div class='ui-block-d'>";
    var j=0;
    var stop=false;

    if(!stop){
      $(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function(){

        var toc= '';
        $.each(json.tcontent, function(index, item) {
          if (j > 2) { j = 0; }
          toc += grid[j] + item.url + '<div class="grid">' + "<a><p class='gridtext'>" + item.Chapter + ":" + item.Name  + "</p>" +  "</div>" + "</a>" + "</div>"
          j++;
        });

        $(toc).appendTo(".ui-grid-b");

      });
      stop=true;
    } 


    </script> 


  </div>

  <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
    <h2>(c) Darragh O'Connor </h2>
  </div>







</div>


</body>            

</html>
```

Comment: Try to use localStorage.setItem('flag', 'true') and get this value as localStorage.getItem('flag') , you can set and get in every loop as you want..More...1) http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp 2) http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: You could check if the nav contains any items: if ($(".ui-grid-b > div").length > 0) //no need to fill,  or you can also just empty the nav each time before filling it: $(".ui-grid-b").empty().append(toc);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ezanker 's advice I used the line  $(".ui-grid-b").empty().append(toc); to clear the grid each time the page is loaded. I ran into a further problem of the grid not setting which resulted in there sometimes being only one or two tiles on the first line but that was amended by simply moving the initialisation of the var j. I also amended the code so it can read in Json from a file and not from within the script which is clearer and more efficient. Here is the working code:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">

  var grid= new Array();
  grid[0]= "<div class='ui-block-a'>";
  grid[1]= "<div class='ui-block-b'>";
  grid[2]= "<div class='ui-block-c'>";
  var j=0;

  $(document).on("pageinit", "#Page1", function(){


    var imp= "Json/contents.json";
    $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {
     j=0; 
     var toc= '';
     $.each(data.tcontent, function(index, item) {
      if (j > 2) { j = 0; }
      toc += grid[j] + item.url + '<div class="grid" style="background-color:#00ffff;">' + "<p class='gridtext'>"  + item.Name  + "</p>" +  "</div>" + "</a>" + "</div>"
      j++;
    });


     $(".ui-grid-b").empty().append(toc);
   });
  });


  </script>
```